# Use JavaMail 1.5 with XPages

Tags: osgi, xpages, jakarta-mail

I have a XPage application that should read mails from GMail via IMAP (and SSL) and store them in a nsf-database.

For this purpose I need JavaMail 1.5.

After reading some posts I came to the conclusion that I have to build my own OSGI-Plugin.
Following John Dalsgaard's blog on http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/ I was able to wrap the JavaMail 1.5 jar-file into the OSGI-Plugin. The plugin exports all JavaMail packages so I can use them in my XPage application.

In my XPage there is some java code that tries to establish the connection to GMail. But the connection always timed out, so I turned on the debug option for javamail. The debug showed that my java code still used javamail 1.3 (the one supplied by the domino server).

Therefore I moved my java code into the OSGI-Plugin and exported the package so I can still use it within my XPage. Turning on debug for javamail showed the correct version 1.5. But now I get the exception `javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException` regardless whether I use `imap` or `imaps` as a protocol.

What am I missing? Why can't I use the javamail 1.5 jar-file within the osgi-plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The code of javax.mail is not really OSGi friendly. It uses the Thread context ClassLoader to find instantiate implementations.

You can trick this in the following way:

- install both javax.mail and com.sun.mail.imap into your OSGi container. Version 1.5.2 have the OSGi manifest headers so it should work
- When you call a function of javax.mail api that loads a Provider, set the thread context classloader to a classloader that knows the imap classes for sure.

E.g.:

```
Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
ClassLoader previousCl = thread.getContextClassLoader();
thread.setContextClassLoader(IMAPStore.class.getClassLoader());
try {
    session.getStore("imaps");
} finally {
    thread.setContextClassLoader(previousCl);
}
```

Please note that I have not tested this but the solution should look similar. You might have to put more javax.mail commands into the try block (e.g. getting the session).

**Less ugly solutoin**

A less ugly solution is if you skip the usage of javax.mail API and use the classes of imap directly.

E.g.:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(...);
Store imapStore = new IMAPStore(session, url);
```

Very often when SPI or similar solution is used in Java EE, the same functionality can be achieved by skipping the factory mechanism (that uses thread context classloader and other tricks) and instantiating the implementation classes directly.

**Update**

In the commant it is stated that there is an exception:

```
com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed incompatible with javax.activation.DataContentHandler
```

The reason seems to be that the javax.activation.* package is available twice in the OSGi container. Ones it comes from the JDK and it also comes from one of the bundles. The issue is similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976985/com-sun-mail-handlers-text-plain-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-activation-datacontenth) and the cause comes from the duplicated packages, too.

However, the real cause is the usage of Thread Context ClassLoader again. If you have a look in the source where the exception is thrown, you will see that the Thread Context Classloader is used to load the class. This is an issue as I guess the TCC is the system classloader while javax.mail is wired to the javax.activation bundle.

I can imagine the following options right now:

- Remove the javax.activation bundle. This might fixes the issue as in that case every bundle will wire to the system package. However, you can still get ClassNotFoundExceptions later... Fighting against classloader bad practice :).
- Remove javax.activation from the system packages. In that case everyone has will wire to the bundle. However the same issue can happen that javax.activation bundle (or TCC) cannot see the class that should be loaded.
- Find a point in the stacktrace where you can change TCC and set a ClassLoader that sees all of the necessary classes. This is again the common trick for monoholitic technologies (like in the original example, but now for this function call).
- Find a technology that has the features but more OSGi friendly. If you can find one, post it here please :).

Comment: I've tried your solution, but the command thread.getContextClassLoader() raises an AccessControlException and changing the java.policy is no option for our productive server.

Comment: Updated the answer with other potential solution where security should not be an issue

Comment: "changing the java.policy is no option for our productive server." sounds weird. with app specific param, you can explain it to admins to do so.

Comment: @Balasz your "less ugly solution" is partly working: partly because I can connect to the mail server with imaps, I can read all mail headers, too, but if I try to read the message body with message.getContet() I get an exception 'com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed incompatible with javax.activation.DataContentHandler'

Comment: @DetlefBirkholz A stacktrace (and probably sample code) would help a lot to find the answer. You could add it to the end of your question or put it up to somewhere and link it from the comment.

Comment: The cause might be that javax.activation packages exist in one of your bundles and also in JDK. However, without a stacktrace it is hard to find out the real cause.

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos I've posted the stack trace to paste.bin http://http://pastebin.ca/2874341

Answer (score 0):

I found this jar in maven central:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.mail|javax.mail-api|1.5.2|jar

It seems to be a valid OSGi bundle. Maybe that helps?

Comment: I'm sorry but that wasn't the solution: the javax.mail-api-1.5.2.jar is missing all com.sun.mail.*-packages that are needed for imap. And if I take the javax-mail-1.5.2.jar (also from the maven central), the result is the same as with my javamail 1.5 jar --> NoSuchProviderExpection

Comment: That's the wrong jar file, you want [this one](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.2/javax.mail-1.5.2.jar).  Still, you might have the class loader problem described below.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need Java 1.5.2 mail? I don't think so. What you need are the [Google enhanced IMAP classes](https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/) and the code [I wrote in January](http://notessensei.com/blog/2014/01/gmail2notes-in-less-than-300-lines.html). In a nutshell:

```
/** ========================================================================= *
 * Copyright (C) 2014 Stephan H. Wissel                                       *
 *                                                                            *
 *  @author     Stephan H. Wissel <stephan@wissel.net>                        *  
 *                                                                            *
 * @version     0.1                                                           *
 * ========================================================================== *
 *                                                                            *
 * Licensed under the  Apache License, Version 2.0  (the "License").  You may *
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License.  You may obtain a *
 * copy of the License at <http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0>.       *
 *                                                                            *
 * Unless  required  by applicable  law or  agreed  to  in writing,  software *
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT *
 * WARRANTIES OR  CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.  See the *
 * License for the  specific language  governing permissions  and limitations *
 * under the License.                                                         *
 *                                                                            *
 * ========================================================================== */
package com.notessensei.gimap;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.FetchProfile;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.Item;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
import lotus.domino.NotesThread;

import com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailFolder;
import com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailMessage;
import com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore;

public class GMail2Notes {

    public static int   MAX_TEST_COUNT  = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NotesException, MessagingException {

        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("GMail2Notes username@gmail.com password nsfFileName");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Starting for " + args[0] + " to " + args[2]);
        NotesThread.sinitThread();
        lotus.domino.Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
        Database db = s.getDatabase("", args[2]);
        GMail2Notes g2n = new GMail2Notes(args[0], args[1]);
        g2n.addExcludedLabel("Spam");
        g2n.addExcludedLabel("Trash");
        int resultCount = g2n.importMessages(s, db, "All Mail");
        System.out.print("Messages imported:");
        System.out.println(resultCount);
        NotesThread.stermThread();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private final String        userName;
    private final String        passWord;
    private GmailSSLStore       store           = null;
    // set it to false for complete import
    private boolean             isTestMode      = true;

    // Labels we don not want to import
    private final List<String>    excludedLabels  = new ArrayList<String>();

    public GMail2Notes(String usr, String pwd) {
        this.userName = usr;
        this.passWord = pwd;
    }

    /**
     * Add a folder name to the list we are not interested in
     *
     * @param label
     */
    public void addExcludedLabel(String label) {
        this.excludedLabels.add(label);
    }

    public List<String> getSystemFolderNames() throws MessagingException {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        GmailSSLStore store = this.getStore();
        Folder[] folders = store.getFolder("[Gmail]").list();
        for (Folder f : folders) {
            result.add(f.getName());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int importMessages(lotus.domino.Session s, Database db, String systemFolderName) throws MessagingException {
        int result = 0;

        // The object to move message to
        Mime2Doc md = new Mime2Doc();

        // Getting gMail ready
        GmailFolder f = this.getSystemFolder(systemFolderName);
        f.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = f.getMessages();
        FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
        profile.add(GmailFolder.FetchProfileItem.CONTENT_INFO);
        profile.add(GmailFolder.FetchProfileItem.LABELS);
        profile.add(GmailFolder.FetchProfileItem.MSGID);
        profile.add(GmailFolder.FetchProfileItem.SIZE);

        f.fetch(messages, profile);
        int count = 0;
        for (Message message : messages) {
            result += this.importOneMessage(s, db, md, message);

            // For testing we don't run through all of them
            count++;
            if (this.isTestMode && count >= MAX_TEST_COUNT) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (f.isOpen()) {
            f.close(false);
        }
        this.cleanup();
        System.out.println("Done");

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * We need a delivered date so documents don't show up in SEND
     *
     * @param doc
     * @param sender
     */
    private void adjustDeliveredDate(Document doc, Address sender) {
        String senderName = sender.toString();
        if (!senderName.equalsIgnoreCase((this.userName))) {
            try {
                Item PostedDate = doc.getFirstItem("PostedDate");
                doc.copyItem(PostedDate, "DeliveredDate");
                doc.save();
                PostedDate.recycle();
            } catch (NotesException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Strips leading \ from messages
     *
     * @param rawLabel
     * @return label Stripped from Backslash
     */
    private String cleanLabel(String rawLabel) {
        return (rawLabel.startsWith("\\") ? rawLabel.substring(1) : rawLabel).trim();
    }

    private void cleanup() {
        if (this.store != null && this.store.isConnected()) {
            try {
                this.store.close();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.store = null;
    }

    private GmailSSLStore getStore() throws MessagingException {
        if (this.store != null) {
            return this.store;
        }
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", "5000");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", "5000");
        props.setProperty("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "gimaps");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        this.store = (GmailSSLStore) session.getStore("gimaps");
        this.store.connect(this.userName, this.passWord);
        // Ready for connection
        return this.store;
    }

    /**
    * can be: All Mail, Drafts, Important, Sent Mail, Spam, Starred, Trash
    **/
    private GmailFolder getSystemFolder(String folderName) throws MessagingException {
        GmailSSLStore store = this.getStore();
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("[Gmail]").getFolder(folderName);
        return (GmailFolder) folder;

    }

    private int importOneMessage(lotus.domino.Session s, Database db, Mime2Doc md, Message message) {
        int result = 0;
        try {
            GmailMessage g = (GmailMessage) message;
            Address sender = g.getSender();
            String[] labels = g.getLabels();
            System.out.print(g.getMessageID());
            if (labels != null) {
                System.out.print(", ");
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(labels));
            }

            if (this.processThisMessage(labels)) {
                result = 1;
                Document doc = db.createDocument();
                InputStream in = g.getMimeStream();
                md.importMail(s, in, doc);
                this.moveDocToFolders(doc, labels);
                this.adjustDeliveredDate(doc, sender);
                System.out.println(" - processed");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" - skipped");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: record the message for follow-up
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Moves doc to folders as needed
     *
     * @param doc
     * @param labels
     */
    private void moveDocToFolders(Document doc, String[] labels) {
        if (labels != null) {
            for (String label : labels) {
                this.movetoMatchingFolder(doc, label);
            }
        }
    }

    private void movetoMatchingFolder(Document doc, String folderCandidate) {
        // TODO handle the SENT folder, Draft folder
        if (folderCandidate != null && !folderCandidate.trim().equals("")) {
            try {
                String realFolder = this.cleanLabel(folderCandidate);
                if (realFolder.equalsIgnoreCase("inbox")) {
                    doc.putInFolder("($Inbox)");
                } else if (realFolder.equalsIgnoreCase("drafts")) {
                    // TODO handle Drafts
                } else if (realFolder.equalsIgnoreCase("sent")) {
                    // TODO handle SENT
                } else {
                    doc.putInFolder(realFolder, true);
                }
            } catch (NotesException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean processThisMessage(String[] messageLabels) {
        boolean result = true;

        // If the message has no labels we do process it
        if (messageLabels != null && messageLabels.length < 1) {
            for (String rawLabel : messageLabels) {
                String cleanLabel = this.cleanLabel(rawLabel);
                if (this.excludedLabels.contains(cleanLabel)) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Let us know if that worked for you

Comment: That approach might work for GMail, but I also have to connect to t-online, web.de, 1&1 and so on. All of them use imap with ssl and they all time-out if I use javamail 1.3. But with javamail 1.5 I can connect without a problem (tested with a small java program outside domino). Therefore any hints how I can get javamail 1.5 to work with xpages are welcome.